# Azure Stream Analytics Job cannot detect either input table or output table

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I'm new to the Azure Stream Job, and I want to use the reference data from Azure SQL DB to load into Power BI to have streaming data.
I've set up the storage account when setting up the SQL input table. I test the output table (Power BI) which is also fine, no error.

I tested both input table and output table connection, both are successfully connected, and I can see the input data from Input preview.

But when I tried to compose the query to test it out, the query cannot detect either input table or the output table.
The output table icon also grey out.

Error message: Query must refer to as least one data stream input.

Could you help me?

[image]

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The test query portal will not allow you to test the query if there are syntax errors. You will need to correct the syntax (as seen by yellow squiggles) before testing.

Here is a sample test query without any syntax error messages:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stream Analytics does require to have at least one source coming from one of these 3 streaming sources: Event Hubs, IoT Hub, or Blob/ADLS. We don't support SQL as a streaming source at this time.
Using reference data is meant to augment the stream of data.
From your scenario, I see you want to get data from SQL to Power BI directly. For this, you can actually directly connect Power BI to your SQL source.

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)